Veracode CWE Id 95 Security concerns with FileAPI.js
I'm currently working on a project, and we've identified a security flaw reported by Veracode with CWE ID 95, which corresponds to Eval Injection. The flaw was detected in our FileAPI.js script,specifically around the area where dynamic code execution or eval is used.
Problem: The static analysis scan flagged our FileAPI.js v2.0.7 file for potential code injection vulnerabilities around line 439.
parseJSON: function (str){
                var json;
                if( window.JSON && JSON.parse ){
                    json = JSON.parse(str);
                }
                else {
                    json = (new Function('return ('+str.replace(/([\r\n])/g, '\\$1')+');'))();
                }
                return json;
            }

What I've Tried:
parseJSON: function (str){
    var json;
    if( window.JSON && JSON.parse ){
        json = JSON.parse(str);
    }
    else {
        console.error("window.JSON && JSON.parse is not available");
    }
    return json;
}


How can I handle this issue?
EDIT:
line 439 :json = (new Function('return ('+str.replace(/([\r\n])/g, '\\$1')+');'))();

To be clear, does the "What I've Tried" code block result in the same error/warning from Veracode? Or have you not re-submitted that second code block method to be checked?

Also, which line is line 439?

@TylerH I have edited the question mentioning code exact line number
I resubmitted the code for scan and ran some few scans .Among all reports,  flaw was reported in one report.
